# Native App Crashes

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am getting following stack trace when native app get crashed. Could someone help me to find the root cause of this crash?

```
00  pc 000000000004ad30  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01  pc 00000000000484c3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
02  pc 000000000001dd99  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
03  pc 0000000000019521  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
04  pc 0000000000017160  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
05  pc 000000000031be69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+252)
06  pc 00000000000b4dcb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+866)
07  pc 00000000001bd34d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+308)
08  pc 000000000023a9ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt16AddWeakGlobalRefEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+46)
09  pc 0000000000280233  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI16NewWeakGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+418)
10  pc 000000000008edc3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
11  pc 00000000028f5055  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RenderNode.nCreate+96)
12  pc 00000000028f4dab  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RenderNode.<init>+70)
13  pc 00000000028f4f19  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RenderNode.create+68)
14  pc 00000000026b725f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.View.<init>+762)
15  pc 00000000026b75af  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.View.<init>+66)
16  pc 00000000029cb961  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.widget.TextView.<init>+148)
17  pc 00000000029cb895  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.widget.TextView.<init>+64)
18  pc 00000000000103d1  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_10082_10082 (deleted)**
```